# Why does not coordinatorlayout work with api level 22?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-coordinatorlayout

My `android studio` version is 1.2 and the update available for my android studio is 1.5, now i wanted to use `snackbar` in my application , so i implemented `coordinatorlayout` in my xml file but the application is unable to find `coordinatorlayout`.
I also tried to change it to api level 23 , but in my application i have used `HttpClient` in many classes which is not allowed in api level 23 , so i changed it back to api 22 .

```
      android {
        compileSdkVersion 22
        buildToolsVersion "22.2.0"
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId 'app.efleet.quiksnap'
            minSdkVersion 13
            targetSdkVersion 22
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
                'proguard-rules.txt'
            }
        }
        productFlavors {
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
}
```

Can anyone suggest me what to do without having to change the `HttpClient` codes?
Should i update my android studio to 1.5 ?

Comment: I don't know if this question is about API 22, `HttpClient` or `CoordinatorLayout`. You will get better help if you choose 1 problem to ask about.

Answer (score 0):

Update your dependencies:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
```

Comment: that is my concern sir , i tried to update but getting error in httpclient as httpclient is not supported in api 23 , so what to do in this case ? , i am using httpclient in most of my classes and it will be a hectic to change all of them at once , cant i make it work in api 22 itself ?

Answer (score 0):

You said that:

> Can anyone suggest me what to do without having to change the
>   HttpClient codes?

Try this in your dependenices:

```
compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
```

And there are two problems here, first, look at the title:

> Why does not coordinatorlayout work with api level 22?

And above problem.

Then update them:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
```

And finally, try to rebuild the project.